# Index into an instance in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a method that I would like to use to be able to update any of the elements of a type.
I keep getting the error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'BrandTy'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BrandTy'.ts(7053)

Interface:

```
interface BrandTy {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 catid: number;
 categoryType: string;
 catDescription: string;
 catLevel: number;
}
```

Method called

```
const onInputChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> |     ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
    name: string 
) => {
    const val = (e.target && e.target.value) || '';
    const  _brand: BrandTy = { ...brand };
    
_brand[name as keyof _brand] = val;


    setBrand(_brand);
};
```

I have tried keyof BrandTy as well with the same error and google searches don't seem to help.

Comment: Can you post the full component code?

Comment: The full code is : const onInputChange = (
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  name: string
 ) => {
  const val = e.target && e.target.value;
  
  let _brand: BrandTy = { ...brand };
    _brand[`${name}`] = val; setBrand(_brand); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BrandTy` is not strongly enough typed.

You should convert it to a `Record`

```
interface BrandTy {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 catid: number;
 categoryType: string;
 catDescription: string;
 catLevel: number;
}

type BrandTyStrong = Record<keyof BrandTy, string | number>
```

and also define the name type more strongly

```
const onInputChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> |     ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
    name: keyof BrandTy
)
```